# Like to show/force the user to login when accessing a intranet page.?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-services

Using share point 2007, i need to force an user to log in before the page is accessed.

May be re-direct him to login page or show the prompt box with username and password.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you turn on anonymous access then people will need to login to access the SharePoint site.

By default this will be using Windows Authentication, which means that if the site is in the intranet zone then IE will perform the login automatically as the currently logged in windows user.